# Why does my return value become undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function getStartDate(dateToTest) {
    var dateToUse;
    // The function here doesn't matter.  I get the same result even if I use "if (1 != 1)".
    if (!isAcceptableDate(dateToTest)) {
       dateToTest = dateToTest.addDays(1);
       getStartDate(dateToTest);
    }
    else {
        dateToUse = dateToTest;
        // It's not undefined here.......
        console.log(dateToUse);
       return dateToUse;
    }
}
```

The `dateToUse` value is fine in the `console.log` at the end of this function.  However, when it gets to this function, it suddenly becomes undefined:

```
function getDates(startDate) {
    console.log(startDate);
    // Do a bunch of other stuff.
}
```

Here is how I'm calling this stuff:

```
var baseDate = new Date();
var adjustDate = getStartDate(baseDate);
var dateArray = getDates(adjustDate);
```

Why does my variable with a perfectly valid value at the end of one function lose its value when called upon by another function?

Comment: There is no `return` statement in the first of the two branches.

Comment: In the effort to formulate better and more useful questions for the future, could someone point to things that may have gotten this one downvoted twice?  I feel like there's evidence of research and an effort for clarity.  Just trying to improve.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **return** keyword before **getStartDate** function like

```
     return getStartDate(dateToTest);
```